# mysquli error = mysqli(): HY000/1045

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

this code work on my local server but it's not working on my website
mysql error 1045

```
define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_USER","root");
define("DB_PASSWORD","xxx");
define("DB_NAME","admin00");

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the complete error message, and indicate on which line the error occurs.

Comment: That's access denied, so you provided incorrect login information most likely.

Comment: Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin00'@'cloud08' (using password: YES) in /home/channelk/public_html/lib/database.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/channelk/public_html/lib/database.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/channelk/public_html/lib/database.php on line 19

Comment: My login information 100% ok

My code is ........
<?php
define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_USER","root");
define("DB_PASSWORD","xxx");
define("DB_NAME","admin00");

?>

<?php
 class database{
  public $host  = DB_HOST;
  public $user  = DB_USER;
  public $pass  = DB_PASSWORD;
  public $db_name = DB_NAME;
   
  public $link;
   
  public function __construct(){
   $this->connect();}
   
  private function connect(){
  $this->link = new MySQLi($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->db_name);}}
?>